# Get child's height to carousel slider's height - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, carousel

I have a flutter carousel slider with 2 Containers. There is no width or height set to the Containers. So, the width and height of the container are fit to content.

How can I get the height of that container and set it to the carousel slider's height? Because if not we give it height as a hardcoded double, the container is overflowed in other smartphones.

Comment: Try `height : double.infinity`

Comment: Not working!!!!

Comment: Did you try to wrap it in expanded widget.

Comment: Also add code so that i could understand properly